# How can i remove the titlebar from a popup in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want a popup window in html that has no orders or menus etc just plain space. how can I go on about it with html css or javascript/jquery?

edit: I must use window.open its my only option since I'm using frames and popups in on frame don't show over the others. Also window.createpopup does not work because I'm using safari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons, this is not possible.

Instead, you should use a modal dialog script, such as [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Comment: @user: This is completely, fundamentally, impossible.  You should stop using frames.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a ligthbox jquery plugin, inside it you can place an ajax response, an image or a complete page (inside a frame):
http://fancybox.net/ (I recomend this)
http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you want a simple div to be displayed on the page?  If so, you can use the [jQuery Load function](http://api.jquery.com/load/). The following will load the HTML from another page into a div on the current page.  If you show/hide the div then it will have the effect of being a popup.

**HTML**

```
<div id="divTest" style="display:none;"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#divTest').load('mypage.html', function() {
   $('#divTest').show();
   alert('Load was performed.');
});
```